# Find records with SQL that have overlapping time frames

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wonder how to write a query for a specific scenario. I have a dataset:

```
key valid_from  valid_to    position
a   2019        9999            1
a   2021        9999            2
b   2017        2021            1
b   2021        9999            2
```

and I want to present only this records that do not have overlapping time frames and those with overlapping that have smaller position number, so like that:

```
key valid_from  valid_to    position
a   2019        9999            1
b   2017        2021            1
b   2021        9999            2
```

I would like to do it either in one query or in many, firstly selecting records that do have overlapping time periods, but have no clue how to do it for now.
Maybe someone could help me with this query.
BR
P

Comment: what is your expected output if there are 3 records a,2017,2019 | a,2018,2021|a,2020,2022

Comment: I don't see how your example illustrates the problem you specify.  Perhaps it is the definition of "overlapping".    Perhaps `key` has something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T1 (
    key string,
    valid_from int,
    valid_to int,
    position int);

INSERT INTO PUBLIC.T1 (key, valid_from, valid_to, position)
VALUES  ('a',   2019, 9999, 1),
        ('a',   2021, 9999, 2),
        ('b',   2017, 2021, 1),
        ('b',   2021, 9999, 2);

SELECT a.* 
  FROM T1 AS a
  LEFT JOIN T1 AS b
       ON a.key = b.key
      AND a.position <> b.position
      AND a.valid_from < b.valid_to
      AND b.valid_from < a.valid_to
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.key, b.key ORDER BY a.position) = 1 OR b.key IS NULL;
```